# The 'model' keyword must be followed by a type name on the same line

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I get an exception saying "The 'model' keyword must be followed by a type name on the same line" when i try to load my page.

QuickTimingSpeakerInfo.Controllers.BracketWidgetModel is a class.

in the cshtml file i have the following:

```
@model QuickTimingSpeakerInfo.Controllers.BracketWidgetModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SettingsMenuButton-" + '@model.Guid').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-w"
            },
            text: false
        })
        .click(function () {
            ChooseWidgetInitialize(@Model.TabId, @Model.WidgetId, @Model.EventUID);
        });
    });
</script>...
```

It was working only a short moment ago. Rebuilding does not solve it. How do i resolve this?

Comment: Did you change anything in the BracketWidgetModel class?

Comment: Nope, but i referenced a field further down in the cshtml with '@model.field' instead of '@Model.field'. The problem was with the error message. It looked like it was on line 1 but was not. Shold i delete the question? Or add my own answer? What is the stack overflow way?

Comment: Go ahead and answer it.  Try to show where your code mistake was if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I used @model.field instead of @Model.field.
The error message points to fist line and not the actual line the error was on.